I am having error CS2012 when trying to run my visual studio code in unity (i am new to this)
I made my first script in Visual Studio and saved it to Unity, however, i get this error:
The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.
This is my code:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class moveTriangle : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello, World!");
    }
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}

Any help is much appreciated!

Have you searched out existing Q&A threads about troubleshooting this issue?

I looked through the thread you linked and tried the stuff I understood (restarting my computer, trying to create a new project) and neither worked.

This question was asked and answered at StackOverFlow. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658354/the-requested-operation-cannot-be-performed-on-a-file-with-a-user-mapped-section

Try closing VS and run the scene, this sounds like Visual Studio is hogging the file and preventing Unity from running it. I've personally never even heard of this error before, so I would search it up and find potential reasons - something about your development environment may be misconfigured.
